# Renaming URL with HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am building a web app that puts out a link like the following:

http://www.example.com/portfolio/first-name/

I would like for it to look something like this:

http://www.example.com/model/first-name/

Is this possible within the HTACCESS?

Comment: Yes. What is your exact question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just add an entry:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/first-name/$ /model/first-name/ [L]
```

I used it for my site

Answer (score 0):

If I understand that you want to map that first url to access the second url. Sure, just add an entry:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/first-name/$ /model/first-name/ [L]
```

Is that your question?

Or if you just want to map it to some php file, you can do this:

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/first-name/$ /actualpage.php?param=123 [L]
```

Comment: This is list of all models: http://www.balkanselection.com/model/
When you open some of profil link is http://www.balkanselection.com/portfolio/model-name
but i want link 
http://www.balkanselection.com/model/model-name

Comment: If you just want to map that first one to the second one, then my first rule should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /member.php?username=$1

# /models/member.php <-- models in your case
# /users/member.php or /model/member.php
# member.php <--- Gets member name according to its ID from Database
```

Changes,

```
www.mywebsite.com/member.php?u=2343423423423423234
```

To

```
www.mywebsite.com/Username
```

I used it for my site :) It works fine!